# Ms Access - Script Error When Loading Website in Web Browser Control but Not in a Regular Browser

Tags: html, ms-access

I'm using the Office 365 suite.

What causes script errors to pop up on certain websites in Microsoft Access's Web Browser Control?

The script errors don't show up in IE, Chrome or Edge but do when loading the site in Access's Web Browser Control. This is one of the sites that does it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-html-to-open-link-in-new-tab/

Is there any way to load a site like this in Microsoft Access to where it doesn't get the errors?

TIA! :)

Comment: Obviously, something about the HTML in that page doesn't work nice with Access WBC. The page does eventually load, at least some of it - after responding "Yes" to 11 popups. Two large image items (one has animation) do not load, floating header is missing (except for DONATE button), and footer section is all jumbled. I expect you cannot do anything to correct.

Comment: Ok, learned something new. @dbmitch code does suppress error popups, however, the results I get are as I described before. The page still won't fully render.

Comment: Might be the script is not compatible with IE7, the default mode used by the webbrowser control. If higher version of IE is on system. There is registry hacks to get it to emulate higher version if installed on system but that's so dependent on user system - AND it's a registry hack - not ideal

Comment: dbmiitch, it not being compatible with IE7 makes PERFECT sense. I wasn't aware that the Web Browser Control was still running on IE7 version of IE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to suppress the javascript errors.

Simply turn on silent mode when you load the form
This is same as the setting the ActiveX object property `ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true`

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With WebBrowser0
        .Object.Silent = True 
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: example form]

Comment: As June7 has stated, suppressing the errors doesn't actually fix the page not rendering correctly. I've already tried suppressing errors on other pages loaded into the Web Browser Control. Some pages just never fully load. It looks like they're constantly refreshing and then Access just freezes to where I can't click on anything.